# Python OpenGL Texture Not Being Applied

Tags: python, qt, opengl, glsl, textures

I am trying to use OpenGL and Python to render a multi-colored square, with colors computed based on a texture. However, I only get a black screen. This makes me think that the texture is not being applied, but it seems that no matter how I rearrange the OpenGL calls, nothing other than a black screen appears.

To answer the questions in the comments (as to why fixed function and programmable pipeline calls are used), the goal is for this to be a minimal working example of providing texture example to the GPU, and I did not want to overcomplicate the code with VBOs, VAOs, etc., as I want the code to be as focused on the actual texture element as possible.

I have spent hours on Google and have been unable to find a tutorial using the same frameworks that explains how to make this work. I have read the PyOpenGL documentation, but I cannot find anything that would explain why this code does not work. Any information is greatly appreciated.

The code is listed below:

**Python Code - shader2.py**

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QOpenGLWidget

import numpy as np

from PIL import Image

class Graphics(QOpenGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(720,720)
        self.setMouseTracking(False) 

    def initializeGL(self):
        self.program = glCreateProgram()
        self.fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        
        with open("shader2.frag", "r") as f:
            glShaderSource(self.fragment_shader,f.read())
        glCompileShader(self.fragment_shader)
        if not glGetShaderiv(self.fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            print(glGetShaderInfoLog(self.fragment_shader).decode('ascii'))
        assert glGetShaderiv(self.fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == True
        
        glAttachShader(self.program, self.fragment_shader)
        
        glLinkProgram(self.program)
        assert glGetProgramiv(self.program, GL_LINK_STATUS) == GL_TRUE
        
        glDetachShader(self.program, self.fragment_shader)
        glUseProgram(self.program)

        self.uniform_width          = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 'width')
        self.uniform_height         = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 'height')

        self.texture = glGenTextures(1)
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + self.texture)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture)
       
        # https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmH7I.png
        image = Image.open("colors.png")
        img_data = np.array(list(image.getdata()), np.uint8)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image.width, image.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(self.program, "t"), self.texture)

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        pass

    def paintGL(self):
        glUniform1i(self.uniform_width,     int(self.width()))
        glUniform1i(self.uniform_height,    int(self.height()))
        
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glVertex2f(-1, 1)
        glVertex2f( 1, 1)
        glVertex2f( 1,-1)
        glVertex2f(-1,-1)
        glEnd()
        
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.setGeometry(0,0,720,720)
        
        self.content = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(Graphics(self.content))
        self.content.setLayout(self.layout)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    application.exec()
```

**Fragment Shader - shader2.frag**

```
#version 420 core

uniform int       width;
uniform int       height;
uniform usampler2D t;

out vec3     COLOR;

void main(){
    vec2 point = vec2(gl_FragCoord);
    point -= min(width, height)/2;
    
    COLOR = texelFetch(t, ivec2(sign(point.x)+1,sign(point.y)+1), 0).xyz;
}
```

Comment: Why the mixture of fixed-function and programmable pipelines?

Comment: @genpfault - I want the shader to be called for every pixel, so I’m just using the fixed function vertex calls for simplicity rather than having to worry about VBOs and VAOs when I’m only rendering a single quad.